# You don't have permission to access this site on this server

Tags: c#, asp.net, postman

I have no trouble accessing the https://api.weather.gov/ API using Postman.  But when I write simple .NET C# console app using Visual Studio 2017 using the suggested code snippet from Postman, I get this error.  I am running both Postman and Visual Studio on a corporate VDI.  How can I get it to work on Visual Studio?  This is my code:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/IND/59,75/forecast");

            try
            {
                var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
                var statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                //response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                Console.WriteLine($"Status code = ", statusCode);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to add a User-Agent header key.  The code I added was:

```
            request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Testing API Client");
```

For some reason, Postman works without it.

Comment: The web site specifies this here: https://weather-gov.github.io/api/general-faqs#im-getting-a-403-forbiddenaccess-denied-error-from-the-api

Answer (score -1):

This error was answered in the post: [Current Observation feed from weather.gov forbidden (403)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32641072/current-observation-feed-from-weather-gov-forbidden-403)

You need add the following code after declare the request:

```
request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "MyApplication/v1.0 (http://foo.bar.baz; foo@bar.baz)");
```